# Loop with setInterval

Tags: javascript, replace, setinterval, charat

Sup, hope you all doing well!

I'm tryng to change each piece of a string to a random digit in a realtime loop but something is going bad here

I've shorted the code to find the problem but no sucess atm:

```js
let count = 0;
let timer = setInterval(() => {
let rng = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
let txtOriginal = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;

if (count < 8) {

let txtNew = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = txtOriginal.replace(txtOriginal.charAt(count), rng);
count++;

} else {
count = 0;
}
},500)
```

```html
<p>ABCDEFGH</p>
```

The first run goes as intended, but going foward it starts to change the values in a random order...

Should I try another metod?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing

```
.replace(txtOriginal.charAt(count), rng)
```

When a string is passed to `.replace`, the first instance of the string found is replaced. For example, `'aa'.replace('a, 'b')` results in `'ba'`.

The first go around, no duplicate characters will be found; `textOriginal.charAt(count)` will always return a substring not present anywhere else. But starting at the second go around, now that the text is composed of numbers, `txtOriginal.charAt(count)` may well produce a numeric character that's also present earlier in the string. For example, if the string generated after the first time is `12345678`, and the next iteration produces `22345678`, the resulting

```
.replace('2', rng)
```

will replace the character at the index 0 again, instead of the character at index 1.

Slice the string instead, to replace with the desired character.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
let count = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  const newChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  const text = p.textContent;
  if (count < 8) {
    p.textContent =
      text.slice(0, Math.max(0, count))
      + newChar
      + text.slice(count + 1);
    count++;
  } else {
    count = 0;
  }
}, 500)
```

```html
<p>ABCDEFGH</p>
```

Or, perhaps use an array - adjusting it is a bit more intuitive than adjusting a string.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
let count = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  const newChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  if (count < 8) {
    const textArr = [...p.textContent];
    textArr[count] = newChar;
    p.textContent = textArr.join('');
    count++;
  } else {
    count = 0;
  }
}, 500)
```

```html
<p>ABCDEFGH</p>
```